# aggregate function using alias name and fetch the result into the resultset using the Alias name given for that function which uses alias name

Tags: java, oracle

I have to perform calculation using aggregate function by specifying the alias name inside that function and retrieve the data into my resultset using the alias name given for that aggregate function... when I tried to do that I got an Exception saying "Invalid Identifier" how to resolve this?

**To be more clear**, Am using alias name inside my aggregate function and giving alias name for the final result obtained by this aggregate function. so now my question is how to fetch the value returned by the aggregate function into my resultset? When I try to retrieve that through my Resultset in java code, It is throwing Exception. how to resolve this issue?

my Query:

```
select customername,
       to_char(dt,'ddmonyy'),
       lpad(sum(AliasNAme2),15) as AliasName
from (
  select customername,
         dt,
         sum(traffic) as AliasNAme2
  from table
  where dt >= trunc (SYSDATE -1)
  group by customername,
           dt,
           0,
           0,
           0
)
group by customername,
         to_char(dt,'ddmonyy'),
having customername = 'BB'
```

I got an error **"Invalid Identifier"** when I try to fetch the data using the following java code

```
rs.getInt("AliasName");
```

Comment: try: `rs.getInt("ALIASNAME")`

Comment: Did you try executing this query directly?!

Comment: @R.J ya I executed that query manually . It did not throw error but when I use the same in my java code it is throwing the exception because of  using that alias name

Comment: and the output of that query, showed the column name as *AliasName*?!

Comment: Yes It showed the same

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a space in `rs.getInt("AliasName ").` Please remove and check.